# Кряк оверфлоу по-русски

Tags: поддержка

На [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) завезли уточку:

> [image: уточка]

Будет ли у нас что-то подобное? Или по политическим причинам не прошло? ;)

Comment: на enSO тоже уже работало

Comment: @Grundy на всех англоязычных сайтах есть, как я понимаю.

Comment: Как я понял - утка не может в не английский :-)

Comment: @Grundy stupiduck

Comment: @Grundy посмотрим, ответят ли на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308604/339911)

Comment: Ага, тоже хотел спросить :-)

Comment: Что это? Реинкарнация Скрепыша?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. На международных сайтах, к сожалению, «пасхалки» в этом году не будет.

Comment: А какие на это причины?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Не хватило сил.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky там перевести-то несколько коротких строк всего можно было, имхо.

Comment: Меня раздражает эта утка. Если выбрать "I hate this duck", то она погрустит и изчезнет.